# Working With SkyDrive

Tags: onedrive

I am trying to write a WPF 4.0 app that can upload, download, and delete files on SkyDrive.

There are a bunch of Google hits, and various "solutions" on CodePlex and other places, but none work, or have zero documentation.

The closest matches are this.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live/default.aspx, which is for Metro, and this http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SkyDrive-Photo-API-sample-f06778ae/ which is for WP7.

I looked through the phone app sample, and all it does is return a little info. No upload/download functionality.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Any examples of upload and downloading files?

Thanks

Comment: 3 months ago I looked for the same, and did not find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [SkyDrive API (Live Connect)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826521.aspx)?
I've found a lot of help and code examples there...

Answer (score 0):

You can use there rest api to implement functionalities like upload,download and delete.You can read all the information from this link it was helpful for me also.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826531.aspx